# Text Field with an Action not working on iPad

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield

I have created a button in my text field and calling my `bookMarks` method. That works fine with iphone. If I create a button in a toolbar and call this method, still works fine. it's just not working in my text field. is there a way to fix this problem? Thanks..

```
 [bookMarkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(bookMarks:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    locationField.leftView = bookMarkButton;
```

bookMarks method

```
- (void)bookMarks:(id)button {

    if (self.bookmarkPopoverController.popoverVisible) {
        [self.bookmarkPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.bookmarkPopoverController = nil;
    } else {
        ViewBookmarkViewController * viewBookmarkViewController = [[[ViewBookmarkViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
        viewBookmarkViewController.delegate = self;
        [viewBookmarkViewController setBookmark:[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]
                                        url:self.url];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewBookmarkViewController] autorelease];

        navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            self.bookmarkPopoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController] autorelease];
            [self.bookmarkPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:button
                                                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                                   animated:YES];
        } else {
            [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you put in a breakpoint or NSLog statement to see if your `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` conditional clause is even called?

Comment: yes.. it crashes after `self.bookmarkPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:`

Comment: I think questions that contain "It doesn't work" or "it crashes" should be destroyed to be put out of their misery.  Would you tell your mechanic "My car doesn't work...why?"?  NO!

Comment: if you don't know the answer, you don't have to write something.. if I knew why it doesn't work, I would fix it..

Comment: You don't have to know why, but at least give some sort of info...*how* does it crash?  Error messages?  Don't just say "This lump of code doesn't work"

Comment: well next time i will ask u what to write buddy.. I pasted my code and if u think that is not considered as 'info', what is info then? error messages?? like `SIGABRT` or 0x1465022 0x115acd6 0x1466cbd 0x13cbed0

Comment: Yes, error messages like that are very helpful in diagnosing the problem.  When you just say "it doesn't work" then it could mean so many things.  Maybe no action happens?  Maybe it crashes?  Maybe the wrong action happens?  Of course the source is also helpful, but it is not enough on its own.  We don't know anything about your project, so please try to be as detailed as possible.  SIGABRT is useful because it indicates that you probably haven't enabled exception breakpoints, and if you do you will get more info about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't u add ControlEvent for textField:

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(bookMarks:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**EDIT:** To differentiate buttons add Tag 0 and 1 to two buttons respectively;

Now your method is:

```
- (void)bookMarks:(id)sender 
{ 
  if([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
  {
   UIButton *curBtn = (UIButton *)sender
   if([curBtn tag] == 0)
   {
     // any action for button 1
   }
   else if([curBtn tag] == 1)
   {
      //refresh uiWebView
   }
  }
 else
 {
   //your code
   //present your popover for ipad
   [[self.bookmarkPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:yourtextFeild.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. worked well.. just one problem.. I have 2 buttons in my textfield.. right one is for refreshing the UIWebView.. if I use the code above, refresh button will work as bookmarkButton. How can I differentiate buttons?